# Delaunay Triangulation in 3D

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, triangulation

I am planning to construct a CAD model from a point cloud.

- The point cloud is a list of unique 3D point.
- The CAD model is a list of triangles (2D triangles not tetrahedra) in a 3D space.

Lets say there is a triangle with vertices $(A,B,C)$ and there is a point $P$.

I would like to check if the $P$ is inside the inner region (sphere, ellipsoid or what ever based on Delaunay) belonging to the triangle.

Based on Delaunay method, how can I perform such a check?

I am looking for the mathematical details not just a English description.

Comment: I believe a direct use of the Delaunay "triangulation" in higher dimension yields higher dimensional "triangles", so in 3D you would obtain tetrahedra, not 2D triangles. There may be methods or heuristics to pick some "good" triangles from a Delaunay tetrahedralization  though, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you looking to implement a *"point in polyhedron*" test? The extension of 2D [*"point in polygon*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) to 3D? In your case, the polyhedron being one or more closed objects defined by triangle meshes.

Comment: @NominalAnimal One way to compute a 2D Delaunay triangulation is to ensure every triangle satisfy a "Delaunay condition" : the circumcircle of the triangle must not have any point (from the point cloud) in its interior. So I assume the question is about how to transpose this into 3D, which normally uses spheres circumscribing a tetrahedron.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, Consider that I have a depth image point cloud like [this](https://info.photomodeler.com/kb-images/densifyPointCloud.jpg). Forget the color at the moment. I look for a method to convert this point cloud to a mesh. Unfortunately, in 3D the points are not projectable in a 2D plane nor triangles define a circum-hypersphere which is referred in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#d-dimensional_Delaunay).

Comment: @N.Bach, but when I am comparing a poin against a triangle, how can I create a tetrahedron from a triangle? Do you think I should consider the sphere with minimum radius circumscribing the triangle?

Comment: Well, usually you would compare a vertex against a tetrahedron, not a vertex against a triangle... Which is why you'd usually consider Delaunay in 3D to yield tetrahedra. If you don't fixate on the Delaunay method, there is plenty of literature on the problem of converting a point cloud into a mesh (or some other CAD model), and this problem is called **surface reconstruction**.

Comment: @N.Bach, Thanks a lot for mentioning surface reconstruction. It seems even in surface reconstruction Delaunay method is used according to [this paper](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/pubs/sm.pdf). However, I need to study its details.

Comment: From memory, the power crust you linked relies on an approximation of the medial axis, which you can obtain with "polar" vertices of a Voronoi diagram, and the Voronoi diagram is dual to a Delaunay triangulation... Well, this problem is fairly difficult overall, depending on what properties you want in the end.

Comment: @N.Bach, I would like to start with the simplest methods at the moment. Later, I will look for the more complicated ones.